# How to setup webpack to copy files in VS Code

Tags: webpack, node-modules, visual-studio-code

I have started a new personal project in VS Code.  I am new to VS Code, and webpack.

I created a new angular project by running the following commands:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new CyclingApp
```

This resulted in the following file structure:

[image: FileStructure]

I have read that the `node_modules` should never be referenced by for instance, a `script` tag to include the minified `.js` files.

I would like to take the minified files out of `node_modules` and place it into a public folder, for instance, `./scripts`.

At the moment, when I want to run my app, I use the following command `ng serve --open`.

When I run this, I can see that webpack is active, and is doing some stuff (Will need to go read up on this more).

Where does it get this build commands from?  I would like to go and set my 'copying commands' there as well, but I do not see any webpack.config.js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to copy minified files out `node_modules` as webpack will automatically do this for you. webpack is not a task runner like *gulp* or *grunt* but a *asset bundler*.

Firstly have a quick read on [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) then look at how [webpack works](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/).

In very simplified way this is what webpack does;

You define a configuration file in which you specify a *main* file of your app. Webpack will read this file and look for any `import` or `require` statements that import modules. If it does find any then it will bundle these into one file. For each module included it will also look for more import statements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and simple overview

Comment: @monstertjie_za no problem at all.